# Best strategy to archive specific records from RDS to a cheaper storage in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, archive, amazon-simpledb, amazon-glacier

I have the following requirements:

- For every deleted record in RDS we need to archive it into somewhere cheaper on AWS.
- Reduce storage cost
- Not using Glacier
- Context oriented (e.g. a file per table)
- re-import is not a requirement

I'm not an experienced user with AWS, so I'm still a bit lost among the amount of options it has to offer and I'd like to know if you have more ideas to help me clear it out.

Initial thoughts:

1. The microservice that deletes the record, might send it to a broker (RabbitMQ for e.g.) and another microservice (let's call it `archiver`) will listen to it, write into a file, zip and send to S3. This approach has some technical challenges though: in order to make sense create big files, I need to wait the queue to growth a bit, wrap it into a stream and zip inside S3. The transaction control is very weak as well, since file writing and ack on messages are signal based i.e. I'll remove the messages from the broker just after the file is created.
2. Add a new column to the "archiveble" tables as "deleted (bool)" and run a separate job fetching only those records and saving them into S3. **Discarded** they don't want the new microservice with access to other's databases.
3. Following the same approach as in the first item, but instead of save into S3, save into a cheaper database. SimpleDB?

Comment: Can you give an idea about the size of deleted data we are talkign about? How many records and size per day/month/year.
While firehose is a great solution, it costs quite a lot. For example, my application spends close to 20% of it's AWS cost on Firehose. And we are looking at alternates.

Comment: @Nishit it is about 1gb of data per month

Comment: 1GB per month in S3 storage would cost 2 cents (another 3 cents for ingestion via Firehose), hence a total of 5 cents, and in RDS it would cost around 10 cents. Is that such a big difference that you want to build this functionality?

Comment: @Nishit, sorry, I meant 100GB, I think for S3 it will costs around 70 USD/month + 90 USD/month for Firehose.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ & https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/pricing/ for your reference. The total cost for 100GB in S3+Firehose is ~$5. Cost of keeping in RDS is about ~$11. Difference is around $6/month. Still not worth putting in the effort, imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1, but instead of rabbitmq, write it to a kinesis firehose and direct that to an s3 location - it doesn't get much cheaper or easier than that.

Comment: do you think it is cheaper than have another RDS to receive the "deleted data" doing automatic backup to s3 and erasing its data afterwards ?

Comment: I think firehose would be cheaper, and if - as you say - there is no need to be able to reload to data back to RDS, there is little point in running another RDS instance for this purpose.